# Gibbs sampling version for estimating the Dynamic Topic Model (DTM)?

Tags: sampling, inference, gibbs, topic-models

The paper of Blei et Lafferty published at ICML'06 implements a (quite complicated) variational inference (VI) technique for estimating the parameters of the Dynamic Topic Model, see:

http://pdf.aminer.org/000/334/521/dynamic_topic_models.pdf

I believe that an estimation driven by gibb's sampling can do the job. So my first question is: Do you think that GS can be competitive with VI for such complicated model? And the second question is: Does someone know a paper/software that already perform such inference? This can save me a lot of time.

Thank you very much,

Julien

Answer (score 1):

Two recent papers are about it:

1) Arnab Bhadury, Jianfei Chen, Jun Zhu, and Shixia Liu. [Scaling up Dynamic Topic Models](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.06049v1.pdf), In Prof. of World Wide Web Conference (WWW), Montreal, Canada, 2016. (WWW 2016)

2) Scott W. Linderman*, Matthew J. Johnson*, Ryan P. Adams. [Dependent multinomial models made easy: stick breaking with the Polya-Gamma augmentation](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.05843v1.pdf). Neural Information Processing Systems (NIPS), 2015.